# Google Maps not installing?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have Jellybean 4.2.2 on my phone. (I haven't rooted my device)
I recently updated Google Maps but it wasn't working. So I uninstalled it and tried to do a new install. Every time I try to install it from Play Store, an error message is displayed saying the process could not be completed and the installation cancels after every 65% completion.
I even tried installing it on my phone via the .apk file but to no use. An error message was displayed saying package could not be parsed.
Please help me out, I have searched many forums but couldn't find a suitable solution to my problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While downloading from play store make sure you have a good speed internet connection.
You may get the Error "There is a Problem Parsing the Package" Due to following Reasons:

- The Downloaded .apk file is Currupted or not fully downloaded
- You might have turned off “Allow installation of apps from Unknown Sources”
- If the App is not Compatible with the Hardware or the Version of OS you are using.

You may be able to fix the problem trying any of the steps described below:

**1. Allowing Installation from Unknown Sources:**

```
 - Go to your Device Setting Menu
 - Scroll down and Click on Applications
 - Now Check the Box of Unknown Sources to allow installation of non Market Applications
```

After Completing the Above Simple steps you may now try and install the app.

**2.Inspect Your APK File:**

If the Above Fix do not work then you may inspect the apk file. Check that the file is Fully downloaded and is not Corrupted.
If you have downloaded the apk file from any other place rather then Google play store then Make sure you download it from Google play store this time and try to install it.

**3.App is not Compatible with your Device or OS:**

If you are still not able to Get rid of the error then it clearly indicates that the file that you have downloaded is not Compatible with your Device hardware or Operating System.